# Remove spaces between leading numbers in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, how do I remove the whitespace between the leading numbers but keep the whitespaces for the rest of the string for each line?  I'm using regular expressions (regex) in Perl, however the combination of letters/symbols for my Regex gives an incorrect output.

So here is the input with 2 lines of apples:

```
Apples 2 Green 3 Red
Apples 5 Yellow 4 Rotten
```

I want to remove the whitespace between 2 and Green & 5 and Yellow but keep the other whitespaces.

So the output should look like this:

```
Apples 2Green 3 Red
Apples 5Yellow 4 Rotten
```

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;
use warnings;

my $Combine_Leading_Numbers1 = "Apples 2 Green 3 Red";
my $Combine_Leading_Numbers2 = "Apples 5 Yellow 4 Rotten";

$Combine_Leading_Numbers1 =~ s/^(\s\d);
$Combine_Leading_Numbers2 =~ s/^(\s\d);

say $Combine_Leading_Numbers1;
say $Combine_Leading_Numbers2;
```

Comment: `I've been working with regular expressions although unsuccessful` Please include what you have tried.

Comment: This is kind of a weird way to do it, but [it works](https://regex101.com/r/ilvs9G/2)

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down.  This was a nice puzzle where I could not find the right combination using RegEx.

Comment: @user1608954 The question itself isn't bad, but you're expected to show the code that isn't working. Some people might interpret this as a "gimme teh codez" type of question.

Comment: @user1608954 Please read: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have edited the question with more details, including my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;    

my $s = "Apples 2 Green 3 Red";
$s =~ s/^(\S+\s+\d+)\s+/\1/;
say $s;
```

Comment: Great!  This will work!  There are so many combinations with RegEx that at times it really puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

Α one-liner:

```
perl -lpe 's/([0-9])\s/\1/' <(echo 'Apples 2 Green 3 Red \nApples 5 Yellow 4 Rotten')
```